# react.js emojis on chrome doesn't get rendered

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, reactjs, emoji

The render function from a react component won't render emoji on Chrome on a Mac. It works with Safari. An input field works too. Here is the render function. Umlauts works fine.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', backgroundColor: 'gray'}} onClick={this.tryConnectAsTarget}>
            This is a test with emoji and german umlauts ä ü ö ß 
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I'm using Chrome/OSX and i see emoje
http://codepen.io/NourSammour/pen/EKbbaB

Comment: Thank you. You got me to the solution. It was caused by font-weight: bold in the css class.